# Apache won't respond to requests using my domain name, only to requests directed at the server's IP

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, centos6, centos6.6

My VPS host recently suspended my service because my site was under a DDoS attack. When they brought me back online, my IP had changed. I can now only view my site by requesting it's IP http://176.126.69.72/, not using the domain name http://gatewaygaming.net.au/.

I've updated my A records and verified that when I enter the domain name my computer is indeed trying to connect to the right server. Weirdly, if I execute "wget http://gatewaygaming.net.au/" on the server itself I can view the page.

Comment: What happens when you use the domain?

Comment: Good question, it sticks on "waiting for gatewaygaming.net.au" and eventually times out.

Comment: Further info: No connection attempt is logged in access_log or error_log, so I think the issue isn't apache. I'm not sure what it could be though.

Comment: What does that dns record resolve to locally on your client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you made a typo when you updated the A Record.
When I pinged that domain name the IP I got is: **172**.126.69.72 not **176**.126.69.72

Comment: nice one @amace :)

Comment: I have done this before myself.... 172 is also a subnet octet I am use to typing.

Comment: I wasn't able to accept it at the time because Serverfault has a minimum time before you can accept an answer. It's accepted now though, thanks so much for finding my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Type `ping gatewaygaming.net.au` on the server itself, and see if the IP that comes up is the new one - don't think it will be.

Check your apache config to make sure that the server is configured to listen on the new IP, and that the associated hostname is configured as a virtual host on the new IP (if necessary).

Comment: The IP that shows up in this case is 127.0.0.1. The server is definitely listening on that IP, and I'm not using virtualhosts.

Comment: Don't use ping to diagnose DNS, for pete's sake. Use a dns tool. Using ping can result in unreliable results.

Comment: it got the answer!

Comment: I used mxtoolbox too.

Comment: anyway so 127.0.0.1 is why it was connecting on the server itself, and amace has got you the solution

Comment: @PHPaul The point is that it's a bad habit to use an ICMP echo tool to test DNS. Can it work? Sure, sometimes. Will it give you accurate results every time? No. That's why you use tools like `dig`, `nslookup`, etc. to test DNS and use `ping` to test ICMP.